# How to access MMIO registers in Linux kernel with `ioremap()`?

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, memory-mapped-io

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel v5.10.24). And I want to access registers in the SoC which are MMIO based.

So I worked a test module to access them, as follows,

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/ioport.h>

int mmiowr_init(void)
{
    volatile u32 *addr = NULL;
    int ret = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello World!\n");
    addr = ioremap_wc(0x11003000, 0x40);
    if (!addr) {
        printk("Error: Failed to remap 0x11003000\n");
    } else {
        printk("XXXXXX Data_0: 0x%x, Data_1: 0x%d\n", addr[0], addr[1]);
    }
    iounmap(addr);
    return ret;
}

void mmiowr_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bye World!\n");
}

module_init(mmiowr_init);
module_exit(mmiowr_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

But I did NOT get the expected value in this way. This is out of my surprise! Then I tried using `memtool md 0x11003000`, it got the same value as the above code! Finally, I loaded the official driver module for these registers, then both above module and `memtool` can show the expected data.

I checked the driver module, the workflow is as follows,

```c
of_match_node(...);
platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
request_mem_region(start, size, "xxxx");
ioremap(start, size);
```

I inserted my `ioremap(0x11003000, 0x40); printk("Data_0: %x,....);` into above codes to check where I can really access the hardware registers, and found after `platform_get_resource()`, my codes can read the expected data from the MMIO.

So, what is wrong my test module listed above, and what is the necessary step to access MMIOed register from either kernel or user space?

Comment: 1/ Do you understrand what `write combined` means? 2/ Do you know that you have to use specifal IO accessors instead of direct memory read or write? (Hint: look at the io.h header where all those prototypes are listed.) 3/ Where did you get the MMIO address from (that `0x11003000`)? 4/ Are you sure there is no driver loaded for the same memory region? (Hint: check /proc/iomem contents.)

Comment: 1) I don't fully understand the `write combined` means, I tried `ioremap` and `ioremap_nc`,  the same results. 2) I don't know I _HAVE_ _TO_ use special IO accessor instead of direct memory read or write, I would try it later. 3) `11003000` is from SOC's datasheet, the official driver and the device tree file. 4) I am very sure there is no driver loaded for the address (I checked the `/proc/iomem` not found `0x11003000`.  The surprise is I inserted the same codes to the offical driver and found it worked after some function calls. I did the same thing in other projects, no issue found.

Comment: I tried with `readl()` and `__raw_readl()` in my test module, I got the same result. No valid data is read back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tests, I finally figured it out.
Using `ioremap` and `readl()` to access MMIO registers are correct.

The problem I hit is because the MMIO registers are gated by another register (for security and safety).
So to access the MMIO registers with `ioremap()` and `readl()/writel()`, it needs to firstly set the right gate to enable the MMIO space, before doing remapping and accessing.